# Naming of growth models?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, curves

I have a set of equations and I like to explain in words the trend/ behavior of these equations. Unfortunately, I do not know how to name them and hope that you can help and explain me the differences.
The equations and growth models are the following:

[Set of growth models 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkBet.jpg)

[Set of growth models 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysDaT.jpg)

Comment: The first ones are just polynomials, so beyond that you have to use your imagination. When the independent variable ($x$ in this case) becomes large, mainly the coefficient of the highes power term matters. Therefore, you could describe the first ones as polynomials, but differentiate between the two of them by "large coefficient" and "small coefficient".

Comment: Your first pair are degree 2 polynomials and so have quadratic growth.  Your second pair are (translated and scaled) sine functions.  You might investigate the values for larger values of $x$

Comment: both of you, @MattiP. and Henry, thanks a lot. Could we further describe them degressive/progressive and so on?